# custom shape will with image pattern in canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fill

Here is  full code http://jsfiddle.net/4VZQD/3/

In this i need to fill the green, red and gray areas with the image patter. I tried few but failed.

```
var greenImg = new Image();
            greenImg.onload = function(s){
                var greenPtrn = context.createPattern(greenImg,'repeat');
                context.fillStyle = greenPtrn;
                context.save();
                context.beginPath();  
                context.moveTo(start1.x,start1.y);  
                context.lineTo(d.x,d.y); 
                context.arc(x+xVar,y+yVar,(cirRadius2+(cirRadius3-cirRadius2)*status[cnt-1][0]/100),angle * Math.PI/180,(angle-gap) * Math.PI/180,true); 
                context.lineTo(start.x,start.y);
                context.arc(x+xVar,y+yVar,cirRadius2,(angle-gap) * Math.PI/180, angle * Math.PI/180,false);
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            }
            greenImg.src="green.JPG";
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have an undefined value `status[cnt-1]` in this line so fill() is never reached:

```
context.arc(
    x+xVar,y+yVar,
    (cirRadius2+(cirRadius3-cirRadius2)*status[cnt-1][0]/100),
    angle * Math.PI/180,
    (angle-gap) * Math.PI/180,
    true
);
```

Comment: status is an argument passed "function circleBars(context, x1, y1, innerRadius, outerRadius, gap, startAngle, lineColor, writeZone, drawStatus, percentDone, zone, status)" and cnt is initialized. The problem is, it is not getting the count. If should increment from 1 to 12, but the value it gets is 13. Color fill works fine. Can you refer my code?

Comment: i figured it out. passed the count and status values to the onload function. Thanks for your time